# Intellij,Gradle: Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:57850): java.net.SocketException "Socket closed"

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, gradle, groovy, cucumber

I know this problem has been asked couple of times here in SOF and nothing worked for me probably as i am NOT using Android or NOT using remote debugging either.

I am using Intellij 15, trying to run the cucumber tests from gradle. Although i am successful in running the tests but could not DEBUG (program is not stopping at breakpoints)  :( and hence going no where.

it do appears the debugger creates a random port every time i ran the test and i also tried set a static value at debugger.not sure how it works!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into this bug in IntelliJ:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137118

Look in your build.gradle file to see if your compile or test task has a run time dependency.  That was what triggered this bug for me.  Unfortunately the only work around I found was to remove that dependency.

What is happening is that Intellij is launching the dependsOn task with the correct debug port but when that finishes the real process you want to debug isn't getting the necessary debug command line.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I would encounter this error if the "Test Kind" field in the "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog was set to "All In Package".  As I was testing a class, I set "Test Kind" to "Class" and then the debugger worked perfectly.

I haven't tried the other options of this field.

[image]